# How to get user's email and birthday in google+

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
 $client->setClientId('');
 $client->setClientSecret('');
 $client->setRedirectUri('');
 $client->setDeveloperKey('');

$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  var_dump($me);

   // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
  // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php


  $url = filter_var($me['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

  $img = filter_var($me['image']['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

  $name = filter_var($me['displayName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

  $personMarkup = "<a rel='me' href='$url'>$name</a><div><img src='$img'></div>";

  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);

  $activityMarkup = '';
  foreach($activities['items'] as $activity) {
    // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
    // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
    $url = filter_var($activity['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $title = filter_var($activity['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $content = filter_var($activity['object']['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    var_dump($content);
    exit;
    $activityMarkup .= "<div class='activity'><a href='$url'>$title</a><div>$content</div></div>";
  }


  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Google+ Sample App</h1></header>
<div class="box">

<?php if(isset($personMarkup)): ?>
<div class="me"><?php print $personMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if(isset($activityMarkup)): ?>
<div class="activities">Your Activities: <?php print $activityMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
  if(isset($authUrl)) {
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
   print "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
  }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get the user's email id or birthday. Please give the suggestions to get the user's email id and birthday.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: when i add the line $birth = filter_var($me['birthday'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); in the code i got the error Notice: Undefined index: birthday in E:\wamp\www\google\code.php on line 56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bits of missing information from your example which may impact the results you're getting. You may wish to start with the quickstart app at https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php and focus on the sign-in button configuration in index.html and the oauth configuration in signin.php.

In particular, you need to make sure you are requesting the oauth scopes you need in the index.html page. You haven't shown this part in your sample above, but to get birthday information (assuming the user has it set), you'll need to request the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope, and to get access to their email address you'll need to request access to the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and then request the info from the "tokeninfo" endpoint. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth for more info.

The code sample you're showing also shows the activities.get, not the people.get method. You may want to post code that illustrates the exact problem. In this case, however, keep in mind that if the person does not make their birthday public, you won't be granted access to this field.

Comment: hey In the given code can i use $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');

Comment: I had to browse the source, since I'm not that familiar with the PHP library, but it does look like you can specify the scopes this way as well, yes. I'm more used to having a login page and using the Sign-In button to do the initial authentication/authorization (the URL I pointed to with the quickstart).

Comment: yes we can setScopes but the problem is when is trying to add $email = filter_var($me['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); in the above code it is given the error Notice: Undefined index: email in E:\wamp\www\google\code.php on line 56

Comment: The email address isn't returned explicitly as part of this call. Instead, you need to make an additional call (possibly via the apiOauth2Service.php class from what I'm reading, but I can't verify this myself) after you have authenticated to get this info.

Comment: yes you are right. i have to use apiOauth2Service.php to get the email and birthday.